# PythonでExcelからデータ読込後、ブラウザで検索

Tags: python, pandas, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

やりたいこと
Excelからデータを読み込み,yahooで交通費検索したいです。
各項フィルドごとで作業を繰り返したいです。

以下のサイトと同様な処理をPandasで実現したい。

参考:
[PythonでExcelからデータ読込→サイトで交通費検索→Excelへデータ書込](https://www.ex-it-blog.com/Python-Excel-fare)
[Pythonでエクセルから情報を取得して検索エンジンに入力！](https://takeichi.work/scraping-readexcel/)

Excelのデータ

```
   日付        出発    到着    片道・往復  金額
0 2021-01-01   東京    浅草    NaN NaN
1 2021-01-02   池袋    品川    NaN NaN
2 2021-01-03  秋葉原  高田馬場  NaN NaN
```

実現したい結果　1行でループさせます。

```
出発：東京、到着：浅草
出発：池袋、到着：品川
出発：秋葉原、到着：高田馬場
```

現在の結果　1行で全て検索内容に入力されます。

```
出発：東京池袋秋葉原、到着：浅草品川高田馬場
```

ループの処理はどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか。

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。
お手数ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

import pandas as pd

import time

df = pd.read_excel("交通費.xls")
df_from = df["出発"]
df_to =  df["到着"]
df_cnt = len(df)

print(df.head())

for i in range(df_cnt):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Program Files\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get('https://transit.yahoo.co.jp/')

    SearchfromTxt = driver.find_element_by_name('from')
    #SearchTxt.clear()

    SearchtoTxt = driver.find_element_by_name('to')

    SearchfromTxt.send_keys(df_from)
    SearchtoTxt.send_keys(df_to)

    SearchtoTxt.submit()
    SearchfromTxt.submit()
    time.sleep(3)

driver.close()
```

Comment: 仮のURL・要素名やExcelデータにしてしまって、他の人が問題を再現・調査できるソースコードとデータになっていないのでは？

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。質問修正致します。

Comment: 提示されたソースコードの中に検索結果の取得および表示を行う部分が無いように見えますので追記してみてください。最初に目立つ間違いは、`send_keys`のパラメータが`df_from`,`df_to`全体を指定しているように見えるもので、`( )`の中を`df_from[i]`,`df_to[i]`にしてみてください。その後で`SearchtoTxt`と`SearchfromTxt`の両方で`submit()`しているのは何のためでしょう？ それも質問記事で意図等を解説してみてください。

Comment: @kunif 
ご回答ありがとうございます。下記の方法で問題なくいけました。ループの方法知りましたので勉強になりました。また検索するので、submit()一つだけですね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントに書きましたが、`df_from`,`df_to`では全体が送られるので、ループカウンタを行位置として`df_from[i]`,`df_to[i]`のように指定します。
他の指摘も含めて以下のようにすれば出来るでしょう。
`####`でコメントした所を見ておいてください。

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.read_excel("交通費.xls")
df.fillna('',inplace=True) #### NaN を消す

df_from = df["出発"]
df_to =  df["到着"]
df_cnt = len(df)
print(df.head())

#### ドライバオブジェクトは1回作成すれば良いので for ループの前に移動
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Program Files\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

for i in range(df_cnt):
    driver.get('https://transit.yahoo.co.jp/')
    time.sleep(1) #### 必要(気分？)に応じてディレイ
    
    SearchfromTxt = driver.find_element_by_name('from')
    SearchtoTxt = driver.find_element_by_name('to')
    
    SearchfromTxt.send_keys(df_from[i]) #### 行毎のループなので行位置を指定　以下同じ
    SearchtoTxt.send_keys(df_to[i])     ####
    
    SearchtoTxt.submit() #### submit()は１つだけ
    time.sleep(3)
    
    #### 結果を取得して pandas DataFrame の該当位置を更新：参照記事より抽出
    df.iloc[i,4] = driver.find_element_by_class_name('fare').text.replace('円','').replace(',','')

print(df) #### 結果表示

driver.close()
df.to_excel("交通費result.xls",index=False) #### 更新した DataFrame を書き出す
```